# Number with small non-divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to use something along the lines of the fact that for sufficiently large n there is always a number $1<m<n$ that is coprime to n so that $m<n^3/2$.  (In other words, this is clearly true if n is odd, or if it is not a multiple of 6, or not a multiple of 30, etc...) This seems like it is certainly true and in the literature but I cannot find an easy proof or an easy reference,  Does anyone know one?

Comment: What about $m=1$?  or, if you intended to require that $m>n$, use $m=n+1$.

Comment: Did you mean to require that $m$ be prime to $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$?  If so, then use Bertrand to show that there is a prime between $n,2n$.

Comment: Edited to reflect that I don't want $m=1$.

Comment: Ok...so take $n-1$ then.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  The condition $m<\frac {n^3}2$ is redundant (as you are requiring $m<n$ already).  $m=n-1$ always works.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu. Agreed. There must be a typo in the Q. To the  proposer: Please edit this Q  at once, else  it may be put on hold, or closed.

Answer (score 2):

[OEIS A002110](http://oeis.org/A002110) lists the primorials, the product of the first $p$ primes.  They begin, as you have noted, 
$$1, 2, 6, 30, 210, 2310, 30030, 510510, 9699690, 223092870,\ldots$$
and clearly grow quite quickly.  There is a note that for the $p^{th}$ prime they are approximately $p^p$, so the last of these is the ninth one and $9^9=387420489,$ which is of the same order.  The tenth prime, $29$, will not divide this.  This is tiny compared with the primorial.  We can say that every number smaller than $223092870$ is coprime to one of the primes less than or equal to $23$.

Your problem comes at the low end.  Presumably you are prohibiting $1$ for $m$, and when $n$ is $6$ the only other coprime number is $5$, which is not much smaller.  Already by $30$ we have $7$ being coprime.  It would be common to make the statement in the form:  for all $n \gt$ something, there is an $m\gt 1$ and less than $f(n)$ that is coprime to $n$.  $f(n)$ can grow very slowly.  The higher you make the lower limit, the smaller it can be.

As an example, you could say that for $n \gt 30$ there is an $m \gt 1$ and $\lt 2 \log n$ that is coprime to $n$.  I think the constant can come down as the lower limit gets higher.  You can probably get a function that grows more slowly than $\log n$ as well.